# Kendo Grid Is there an event for when a row changes (not selected)?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I was hoping to detect when a Kendo grid's row changes, ***by navigation as opposed to selecting***.

By this I mean I would have a grid with selectable: false, in batch edit mode, and I would like to update the data source (in code) when the user tabs to a new row (just as Access does).

I have looked at [this example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/events) and changed the following properties..

```
selectable: false,
navigatable: true,
editable: true,
```

Unfortunately the changed event does not  when seem to fire for tabs or arrow keys (when in navigation mode).

Would anyone know any other way I can do as described above (ie know when we have changed row via navigation)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the edit event to determine whether you're in a new row.

[Here you go](http://dojo.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/UdorU):

```
selectable: false,
navigatable: true,
editable: true,
edit: function(e) {
    if (e.sender.cellIndex($(e.container)) === 0 && 
        $(e.container).closest("tr").index() !== 0) {
        console.log("next row; update DS");
    }
},
```

You could also store the last row you were in and determine the change using that, if switching between rows in other ways than by tabbing (or when tabbing backwards) is relevant.

If you don't want the grid to be editable, it's more difficult. Here's a quick hack:

```
 var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
 var elem = $(grid.table)[0];
 var handlers = $._data(elem, "events")["keydown"][2];
 var oldHandler = handlers.handler;

 // replace the existing event handler attached by kendo grid
 var newHandler = function (e) {
     oldHandler(e);

     var current = grid.current();
     var closestRow = $(current).closest("tr");
     var rowIndex = $(closestRow).index();

     if (rowIndex !== grid._lastNavRowIndex) {
         if (typeof grid._lastNavRowIndex !== "undefined") {
             kendoConsole.log("we just changed to row " + rowIndex);
         }
         grid._lastNavRowIndex = rowIndex;
     }


 };

 handlers.handler = newHandler;
 });
```

Try it [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/UdorU).

Comment: Hi Lars, thank you once again, yes using a variable to save off "last current row", and using the event as above we can get row changes when (changing via tab key) for backwards tab as well as forwards. The only thing we miss is if navigation is done in "non edit" mode via the arrow keys, when this edit event does not fire. Bummer, trying to see if there is a similar trick for the non edit mode .

Comment: you had "editable" in your question, so I assumed that's what you were going to do; anyway, without that it's more difficult; I added a way to do this, but ... not very pretty (and possibly with bugs, haven't tested much)

Comment: Hi Lars, thank you very much! Sorry for the confusion, I was after row change in either edit or navigation. I set your example to editable, and the above seem to detect the row change when the grid is either in edit or navigation mode. I will do some testing on it, I am just waiting to solving being able to get a grid instance with my Angular setup (which is yet another question here.. sigh). But thanks heaps for this one!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-change) is probably what you are looking for. When you want events related to the data, you have to look for the DataSource events. When you want events related to the UI, than you look at the Grid events.